# Correct Indentation of a buffer with js2-mode in Emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs

Is there a way to automatically correct the indentation of an entire buffer (or region) when editing javascript files with js2-mode in Emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-M-\` runs `indent-region`. If you want to indent the entire buffer, you can do so with `C-x h` (`mark-whole-buffer`) followed by `C-M-\`.

Comment: The only disadvantage of this is that point will jump to (point-min).

Answer (score 2):

I use this regularly to clean up things

```
 (defun cleanup-buffer ()
   "Perform a bunch of operations on the whitespace content of a buffer."
   (interactive)
   (indent-buffer)
   (untabify-buffer)
   (delete-trailing-whitespace)
   (delete-trailing-blank-lines))

 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'cleanup-buffer)
```

UPDATE:
to be precise answer for your question. try `M-x indent-buffer`

Comment: For some reason I have no indent-buffer function.

Comment: @tjb indent-buffer should be added to your init.el https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReformatBuffer